# Physijs scene export/import

Tags: three.js, physijs

Currently I store my three.js application scenes in JSON format and load them in application using `THREE.ObjectLoader()` which return a ready to use `THREE.Scene` object.

According to [Physijs`s](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs) [Basic Setup](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/wiki/Basic-Setup) page I have to use

> Physijs.Scene in place of THREE.Scene

and

> Instead of THREE.Mesh, select the best physics mesh such as Physijs.BoxMesh, Physijs.SphereMesh, or Physijs.ConvexMesh

How can I convert existing `THREE.Scene` with three.js meshes to `Physijs.Scene` with [Physijs](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs) meshes? Are there any way to load scene in [Physijs](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs) way from JSON?

Comment: as per the github page `Physijs` is built on top of three.js. so the question is not very clear.

Comment: I updated my question despite the fact that it should be understandable to any one who ever worked with Physijs